# How can I get rid of annoying "file has been modified outside" message window

Tags: visual-studio

I want to get rid of this... BUT only for one project from solution.. is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Click the Yes button.  There's a setting for it but it doesn't apply to just one project.

Comment: Ye.. but clicking it 1000 times per day is little annoying :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools / Options / Documents / Detect when a file is changed outside the environment
But it will have affect for all projects.

Comment: `BUT only for one project from solution.. is it possible?`

Answer (score 1):

I assume the project you have open also has the particular .cs file tab along the top?  Just close that and it shouldn't happen if you modify it in its own project.

Comment: well.. not my case.. but tnx for answer :)